# Showing a QGraphicsScene as a texture in a full Screen Quad of OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-compat

I need to draw a Quad that occupies my entire view (I'm not sure if viewport is technically accurate) and the load a QGraphicsScene scene onto the Quad as a texture. Here is my code for OpenGLCanvas which simply inherits and reimplements a QOpenGLWidget.

I'm now including all files to compile and reproduce the example

openglcanvas.h:

```
#ifndef OPENGLCANVAS_H
#define OPENGLCANVAS_H

#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include "targettest.h"
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLBuffer>
#include <QOpenGLShader>

class OpenGLCanvas : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit OpenGLCanvas(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    void initializeGL() override;
    void paintGL() override;
    void resizeGL(int w, int h) override;

private:
    float xrot,yrot,zrot;
    TargetTest targetTest;
//    QOpenGLBuffer buffer;
//    QOpenGLShaderProgram shaderProg;

};

#endif // OPENGLCANVAS_H
```

openglcanvas.cpp

```
#include "openglcanvas.h"

OpenGLCanvas::OpenGLCanvas(QWidget *parent):QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
    xrot = yrot = zrot = 0.0;
    targetTest.initialize(100,100);

    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

}

void OpenGLCanvas::initializeGL(){
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
}

void OpenGLCanvas::paintGL(){

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-2, +2, -2, +2, 1.0, 15.0);
    //glOrtho(-1, +1, -1, +1, 1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -7.0);
    glRotatef(xrot, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(yrot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(zrot, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    targetTest.renderCurrentPosition(0,0,0,0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, targetTest.getFBO()->texture());
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glNormal3d(0,0,+1);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3d(-1,-1,0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 2.0); glVertex3d(-1,1,0);
    glTexCoord2f(2.0, 2.0); glVertex3d(1,1,0);
    glTexCoord2f(2.0, 0.0); glVertex3d(1,-1,0);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();


}

void OpenGLCanvas::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{

    Q_UNUSED(width) Q_UNUSED(height)

//    int side = qMin(width, height);
//    glViewport((width - side) / 2, (height - side) / 2, side, side);

//    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
//    glLoadIdentity();
//    glOrtho(-2, +2, -2, +2, 1.0, 15.0);
//    //glOrtho(-1, +1, -1, +1, 1.0, 1.0);
//    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

And here is the code of target test which draws some circles as a QGraphicsScene and renders them to an QOpenGLFramebufferObject:

targettest.h

```
#ifndef TARGETTEST_H
#define TARGETTEST_H

#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QOpenGLContext>
#include <QOpenGLFramebufferObject>
#include <QOffscreenSurface>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QOpenGLPaintDevice>


class TargetTest
{
public:
    TargetTest();
    ~TargetTest();

    void initialize(qint32 screenw, qint32 screenh);
    void finalize();
    void renderCurrentPosition(qint32 rx, qint32 ry, qint32 lx, qint32 ly);
    QOpenGLFramebufferObject * getFBO() { return m_pFbo;}


private:

    const qreal K_LARGE_D = 0.1;
    const qreal K_SMALL_D = 0.02;

    QOpenGLContext *m_pOpenGLContext;
    QOpenGLFramebufferObject *m_pFbo;
    QOffscreenSurface *m_pOffscreenSurface;

    QGraphicsScene *canvas;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem *leftEye;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem *rightEye;
    qreal r;
};

#endif // TARGETTEST_H
```

targettest.cpp

```
#include "targettest.h"

TargetTest::TargetTest()
{
    canvas = nullptr;
    leftEye = nullptr;
    rightEye = nullptr;
}

void TargetTest::initialize(qint32 screenw, qint32 screenh){

    canvas = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,screenw,screenh);
    canvas->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt::gray));

    // Qt OpenGL Initialization.
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setMajorVersion( 4 );
    format.setMinorVersion( 1 );
    format.setProfile( QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile );

    m_pOpenGLContext = new QOpenGLContext();
    m_pOpenGLContext->setFormat( format );
    if( !m_pOpenGLContext->create() ){
        qDebug() << "Open GL Context initialization failed";
    }


    // create an offscreen surface to attach the context and FBO to
    m_pOffscreenSurface = new QOffscreenSurface();
    m_pOffscreenSurface->create();
    m_pOpenGLContext->makeCurrent( m_pOffscreenSurface );

    m_pFbo = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(screenw, screenh, GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    qreal R = K_LARGE_D*screenw/2;
    r = K_SMALL_D*screenw/2;

    qreal horizontal_target_space =  (screenw -4*2*R)/2;
    qreal vertical_target_space   =  (screenh -4*2*R)/2;
    qreal horizontal_margin       =  R;
    qreal vertical_margin         =  R;
    qreal offset = (R-r);



    QList<QPointF> largeTargetUpperRight;
    largeTargetUpperRight << QPointF(horizontal_margin                                  ,vertical_margin)
                          << QPointF(horizontal_margin + 2*R + horizontal_target_space  ,vertical_margin)
                          << QPointF(horizontal_margin + 4*R + 2*horizontal_target_space,vertical_margin)
                          << QPointF(horizontal_margin                                  ,vertical_margin + 2*R + vertical_target_space)
                          << QPointF(horizontal_margin + 2*R + horizontal_target_space  ,vertical_margin + 2*R + vertical_target_space)
                          << QPointF(horizontal_margin + 4*R + 2*horizontal_target_space,vertical_margin + 2*R + vertical_target_space)
                          << QPointF(horizontal_margin                                  ,vertical_margin + 4*R + 2*vertical_target_space)
                          << QPointF(horizontal_margin + 2*R + horizontal_target_space  ,vertical_margin + 4*R + 2*vertical_target_space)
                          << QPointF(horizontal_margin + 4*R + 2*horizontal_target_space,vertical_margin + 4*R + 2*vertical_target_space);

    for (qint32 i = 0; i < largeTargetUpperRight.size(); i++){
        QGraphicsEllipseItem *circle = canvas->addEllipse(0,0,2*R,2*R,QPen(Qt::black),QBrush(Qt::darkBlue));
        QGraphicsEllipseItem *innerCircle = canvas->addEllipse(0,0,2*r,2*r,QPen(Qt::black),QBrush(Qt::yellow));
        qreal x = largeTargetUpperRight.at(i).x();
        qreal y = largeTargetUpperRight.at(i).y();
        circle->setPos(x,y);
        innerCircle->setPos(x+offset,y+offset);
    }

    // Initializing the
    leftEye = canvas->addEllipse(0,0,2*r,2*r,QPen(),QBrush(QColor(0,0,255,100)));
    rightEye = canvas->addEllipse(0,0,2*r,2*r,QPen(),QBrush(QColor(0,255,0,100)));


}

void TargetTest::renderCurrentPosition(qint32 rx, qint32 ry, qint32 lx, qint32 ly){

    if (!canvas) return;
    leftEye->setPos(lx-r,ly-r);
    rightEye->setPos(rx-r,ry-r);

//    m_pOpenGLContext->makeCurrent( m_pOffscreenSurface );
//    m_pFbo->bind();

    QOpenGLPaintDevice device( m_pFbo->size() );
    QPainter painter( &device );
    canvas->render( &painter );
//    m_pFbo->release();

}

TargetTest::~TargetTest(){
    finalize();
}

void TargetTest::finalize(){
    if (canvas){
        delete canvas;
        canvas = nullptr;
    }
    leftEye = nullptr;
    rightEye = nullptr;
}
```

For completion this my mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And my mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

my main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

And finally my mainwindow.ui file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="OpenGLCanvas" name="openGLWidget"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>OpenGLCanvas</class>
   <extends>QOpenGLWidget</extends>
   <header location="global">openglcanvas.h</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

So what happens is that when I run the program I simply see the screen being filled with the color loaded in glClearColor (I've tested changing the color from black and I can confirm this is what I see) and that is it.

So what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I have modified the code in paintGL() with @Rabbid76, however the problem has not changed

UPDATE2: After removing some code as suggested by a comment Now I see this:

[image: Error I see]

What is supposed to look like is the little gray square with the circle should occupy the full screen as it should cover the full quad.

Comment: One thing to note is that `TargetTest::renderCurrentPosition` called from `OpenGLCanvas::paintGL` changes the current GL context using `m_pOpenGLContext->makeCurrent(m_pOffscreenSurface)` but you never rebind the original context.  Try adding `makeCurrent()` in `OpenGLCanvas::paintGL` immediately after the call to `m_pOpenGLContext->makeCurrent(m_pOffscreenSurface)` to see if that changes anything.

Comment: We are on to something. I'm updating the question!

Comment: The problem now is that you are no longer using your FBO `m_pFbo` -- your `QOpenGLPaintDevice` is associated with the default FBO/context which is why the `QGraphicsScene` is being rendered directly to the window rather than the texture.  If you can edit your question to provide a [mcve] I might be able to take a look but without that I'm afraid I'm just guessing.

Comment: The only real things missing are the main and and one .h file. I'll update the question with them, later on.

Comment: @G.M. There you have the complete code. I think the .pro is not necessary, right? Otherwise I'll put it up. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code shown but the main one is with the way you create and use the FBO.  In `TargetTest::initialize` you have...

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setMajorVersion( 4 );
format.setMinorVersion( 1 );
format.setProfile( QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile );

m_pOpenGLContext = new QOpenGLContext();
m_pOpenGLContext->setFormat( format );
if( !m_pOpenGLContext->create() ){
    qDebug() << "Open GL Context initialization failed";
}


// create an offscreen surface to attach the context and FBO to
m_pOffscreenSurface = new QOffscreenSurface();
m_pOffscreenSurface->create();
m_pOpenGLContext->makeCurrent( m_pOffscreenSurface );

m_pFbo = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(screenw, screenh, GL_TEXTURE_2D );
```

In this case, however, there's no need to create a new GL context -- just create the FBO in the current context.  So the code above becomes simply...

```
m_pFbo = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(screenw, screenh, GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Now consider the `TargetTest::renderCurrentPosition` implementation...

```
if (!canvas)
    return;
leftEye->setPos(lx-r,ly-r);
rightEye->setPos(rx-r,ry-r);
QOpenGLPaintDevice device( m_pFbo->size() );
QPainter painter( &device );
canvas->render( &painter );
```

Here you don't bind the FBO so the `QOpenGLPaintDevice` is associated with the default frame buffer and the `QGraphicsScene` is rendered to that rather than the texture attached to the FBO.  The above should become...

```
if (!canvas)
    return;
leftEye->setPos(lx-r,ly-r);
rightEye->setPos(rx-r,ry-r);
m_pFbo->bind();
QOpenGLPaintDevice device( m_pFbo->size() );
QPainter painter( &device );
canvas->render( &painter );
m_pFbo->release();
```

Now the `QGraphicsScene` will be rendered to the correct texture and used as expected by `OpenGLCanvas::paintGL`.

The two changes shown above are the main part of the fix but there are additional issues.  Firstly, from the [`QOpenGLPaintDevice` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglpaintdevice.html#state-changes)...

> When painting to a QOpenGLPaintDevice using QPainter, the state of the
>   current OpenGL context will be altered by the paint engine to reflect
>   its needs. Applications should not rely upon the OpenGL state being
>   reset to its original conditions, particularly the current shader
>   program, OpenGL viewport, texture units, and drawing modes.

This is a bit vague but in the case in hand it is necessary to fix up the viewport once rendering to the FBO is complete.  So change `OpenGLCanvas::paintGL` such that it calls `glViewport` immediately after the call to `TargetTest::renderCurrentPosition)...

```
targetTest.renderCurrentPosition(0,0,0,0);
glViewport(0, 0, width(), height());
```

One other issue is that you potentially make use of GL calls *before* any context has been created and made current.  Your `OpenGLCanvas` ctor implementation is...

```
OpenGLCanvas::OpenGLCanvas(QWidget *parent):QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
    xrot = yrot = zrot = 0.0;
    targetTest.initialize(100,100);
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
}
```

Both `targetTest.initialize(100,100)` and `initializeOpenGLFunctions()` assume a valid GL context.  These should be removed from the ctor and added to the top of `OpenGLCanvas::initializeGL`...

```
void OpenGLCanvas::initializeGL ()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();        
    targetTest.initialize(100,100);
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
}
```

Doing all of the above results in (for me at least) the following frame...

[image]

---

As an aside, you're currently using the old fixed pipeline functionality such as `glVertex3d` etc.  That has been deprecated for quite some time and may not even be available on certain platforms.  Instead you should move to 'modern' OpenGL that makes use of buffer objects, shaders etc.  To that end you might want to look at a website such as [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/).

Comment: I was using the old code becasue at least I thought I understood it. But as it turns out, code never behaves the way that I want it to. Thaank you for your answer. I will be moving on from this example and marking your answer as right